# Consuming "Try..." methods in a nullable paradigm

Tags: c#, nullable

I, for one, am a huge fan of `Nullable`s, and I think it's the greatest thing to hit C# code flow since LINQ. However, this kind of retrofitting does lead to some weirdness. I'm sure we've all experienced using `Try...` methods in the presence of `Nullable`s. It just doesn't make much sense. The following method signature is horrendous:

```
    bool TryFindValue(Key key, Value? value);
```

the obvious problem being that an implementation could return true and out `null`. Also, the compiler doesn't really handle it so well so you need to use `!` (even though you can't *actually* guarantee it isn't `null`) and so you should probably null-check too (therein lies the thing that makes this pattern not work). Ok, so what to do? Well, it's pretty obvious. You do this:

```
    Value? FindValue(Key key);
```

Nice. The bool and the value are all contained in one type. But this makes something else that I do regularly a bit awkward. Say I had the following before:

```
    if(boolValue && TryFindValue(key, out var value))
        DoSomethingWith(value);
    else
        DoSomethingElse();
```

Let's say TryFindValue() is relatively expensive; I don't want to do it unless `boolValue` is true. How do I write this cleanly now? Maybe this?

```
Value? value = boolValue ? FindValue(key) : null;
if(value != null)
    DoSomethingWith(value);
else
    DoSomethingElse();
```

It's not horrendous, but something about it still bugs me. I have the feeling that the `?:` pattern might get a little unreadable if there are multiple condtions. Does anyone have a suggestion for a better pattern, or is this the best we can do for now?

Comment: `if (boolValue && TryFindValue(key, out Value? value) && value.HasValue) { DoSomethingWith(value) } else { DoSomethingElse(); }`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Nope, this uses the `Try...` pattern

Comment: "better", "best", and "clean" are all subjective. Many would say what you have is good enough. There are thousands of ways of doing what you're asking. Are they "better"? Only you can decide.

Comment: In an if statement, it evaluates the conditions left to right - when using the AND operator (`&&`), if the first condition is false, it doesn't bother with the next conditions. If it was an OR then you'd have an issue.

Comment: ... And that's why I voted to close this question. Nothing in your question precluded the use of the Try pattern.

Comment: I think you're both missing the point here, which is that the `Try` pattern is flawed, which is especially obvious with nullables, wherein it may return true but still out a null value which requires an additional null check. It does not compose well. I think the fact that the C# team has provided a pattern that allows you to compose better with nullables underscores this point. So no, I don't agree this is all subjective. There are objective measures like readability, compactness and probabilty of bugs inherent to the choice of pattern.

Comment: @HereticMonkey "Nothing in your question precluded the use of the Try pattern." I did so explicitly where I stated the Try pattern is horrendous. How does that not qualify as preclusion? It's not even opinion-based that the `Try`-pattern is flawed - it's objectively true (case in point in my post).

Comment: The Try pattern is not objectively flawed - that's assuredly an opinion. It works perfectly well; there's a reason it's been added to almost every primitive type; `int.TryParse`, `bool.TryParse`, etc. If it doesn't work smoothly in your specific implementation, maybe the pattern wasn't meant to cover the use case? Maybe the implementation is flawed? The *question* is opinion-based because you're asking for something "better" than what you have, without defining "better" in objective terms.

Comment: The Try pattern is not _generally_ flawed - it is flawed in the context of C#'s nullables (hence the title), in the fact that it returns _two_ values to indicate success or failure. If you don't see that as an objectively problematic method signature, then you and I have very different definitions of "objective", and possibly also what constitutes good code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) to check for nulls:

```
if(boolValue && FindValue(key) is Value value)
    DoSomethingWith(value);
else
    DoSomethingElse();
```

Comment: Oooh, how did I miss this? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderHøst - more like how did you not miss this, the pattern technology is like so fresh maybe 0.1% of c# users will know it and 0.000005% of c# users are actively using it

Comment: @RandRandom Hah, I guess you're right, but we've been using it for nearly a year and it has just spread like wildfire through our codebase (reminiscent of async/await in that regard). We love it, and have even gone so far as to turn all the nullable warnings into errors. Given the extent of our use of it I was surprised I hadn't caught this while reading the docs.